# Logic of RichTextBox.Paste() method

Tags: c#, richtextbox, paste, notepad

What is the internal logic of RichTextBox.Paste() method which pastes data from clipboard to RichTextBox. 
Actually I want to add text to RichTextBox at the location where cursor is there on button click. But when I add text the added text is either selected after addition or the cursoe location is at the start of added text.

Any solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to know the .NET implementation of the control. It is "black box" for you and me. But, you can do unselect and move cursor to the end of text (this 2 things disturb you, not?)

Moving cursor to position 0 (start):

```
richTextBox1.Select(0, 0);
```

Moving to the end:

```
richTextBox1.Select(richTextBox1.Text.Length, 0);
```

Select all text:

```
richTextBox1.Select(0, richTextBox1.Text.Length);
```

Unselect all and move to the end:

```
richTextBox1.Select(richTextBox1.Text.Length, richTextBox1.Text.Length);
```